# delleting bulk comment_type="order_note" from woocommerce DB

Tags: database, woocommerce

wocoommerce after each change status on an order sends comments that types are "order_note" in database.
how can i remove all or disable some of it.
they are 36000 rows in my database now.
some of the order status note comments are not important for us.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRrFF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

36000 rows actually is not that big of a deal. WooCommerce has many performance and database structure related imperfections you should keep in mind, this is probably not one of them.

**Anyway...**

WooCommerce stores it's order notes inside `wp_comments` table, with the comment type set as `order_note`.

You can safely delete these rows as you wish. For example if you want to delete order notes from year 2021 and earlier (and keep only those from 2022), you can run this query:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_type` = 'order_note' AND `comment_date` <= '2021-12-31';
```

If you want to delete order notes for specific order IDs (e.g. for order `12345` and older), you can do it the similar way:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_type` = 'order_note' AND `comment_post_ID` <= 12345;
```

You can implement this SQL query as a PHP script using `$wpdb`, e.g. to automatically delete order notes, that had been created last year or earlier:

```
global $wpdb;

// Delete all order notes created last year and earlier
$delete_before = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( 'last year December 31st' ) );
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM `wp_comments` WHERE `comment_type` = 'order_note' AND `comment_date` <= %s;", $delete_before));
```

You can implement such script as a function and trigger it automatically, either with `wp_schedule_event()` or as a standard CRON job.